# Typescript / Vuejs not compiling for computed property

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I'm starting to learn typescript & Vuejs.

Can anyone explain me why I can't access the account property in data from the computed allChecked()?

```
import * as Vue from "vue";

declare var accounts: any[];    

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vueowner',
    data: {
        accounts: accounts,
        hasAccount: this.accounts.length > 0,
        checkedAccounts: []
    },
    computed: {
        allChecked() {
            return this.accounts.length === this.checkedAccounts.length;
        }
    }
})
```

I have this errors

```
ERROR in index.ts
(25,25): error TS2339: Property 'accounts' does not exist on type 'Vue'.

ERROR in index.ts
(25,50): error TS2339: Property 'checkedAccounts' does not exist on type 'Vue'.
```

Comment: what is in your 'vue' imported file ? a d.ts file ?

Comment: imports are the ones from Vuejs 2 typings

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you need to annotate the return types because TypeScript has difficulties inferring the types of certain methods.

so instead of

```
allChecked() {
   return this.accounts.length === this.checkedAccounts.length;
}
```

try this

```
allChecked(): boolean {
   return this.accounts.length === this.checkedAccounts.length;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Their documentation even says that you have to annotate return types for computed properties and render functions: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Annotating-Return-Types

Answer (score 2):

In your `allChecked` method the `this` keyword isn't referencing the option object you are passing to the `Vue`constructor, but the instance of the `Vue` class itself.

You will need to create a class that extends `Vue` with the properties you wish to add to the original class :

```
import * as Vue from "vue";

class MyVue extends Vue {
    accounts: any[];
    checkedAccounts: any[];
}

const app = new MyVue({
    // (...)
})
```

If you need more information about using Vue.js with Typescript check out this page: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: If true, why this line is working in the data section: hasAccount: this.accounts.length > 0?

Comment: I would guess that it is compiling (since `this` should have the type `any` right there) but not working as you intend it to (probably a `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` at runtime). It should definitely be `hasAccounts: accounts.length`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article to start with
VuejS with Typescript

https://johnpapa.net/vue-typescript/

```
<template>

</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

  export default class App extends Vue {
    public accounts: any = []; 
    public checkedAccounts: any = [];
    public created(): void {
        this.accounts = [];
        this.checkedAccounts= [];
    }
   public allChecked(): boolean {
    return this.accounts.length === this.checkedAccounts.length;
   }
  }
</script>
```